# Использование аллокаторов

Tags: c++

Что представляет собою макрос `__STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(T)`, а так же макрос `__STL_NOTHROW`. И - самое главное -  как ими пользоваться?
Я - в качестве эксперимента - пытаюсь написать "свой собственный" "вектор" и выделить для него память при помощи аллокатора. А точнее просто пытаюсь понять, как пользоваться готовым библиотечным аллокатором?  МОЙ ВОПРОС : В векторе не работают конструкторы. Не знаю почему. Привожу код.

```
template <class T,class A = allocator<T>>
class Vec{
    T* bbb ;
    T* eee ;
    T* mmm ;
    const A* a ;
public :

    Vec(const A & aaa = A())
        :bbb(nullptr),eee(nullptr),mmm(nullptr)
        ,a(&aaa)
        // Здесь всё нормально.
    {}

    Vec( size_t n  ,  const A & aaa = A() )
        :a(&aaa)
    {
        bbb = a->allocate(n) ;
        // Тут что-то не так.
        // Без этой строки - ошибка вермени выполнения.

        uninitialized_fill_n(bbb,n,T()) ;
        eee = bbb ;
        mmm = bbb + n ;
    }

    Vec( int n  , T t , const A & aaa = A())
        :a(&aaa)
    {
        uninitialized_fill_n(bbb,n,t) ;
        eee = bbb + n ;
        mmm = bbb + n  ;
        // Не работает.
    }

    Vec(const Vec< T, A> & vc)
    {
        mmm = uninitialized_copy(vc.bbb,vc.mmm,bbb) ;
        eee = uninitialized_copy(vc.bbb,vc.eee,eee) ;
        // Не проверял.
    }
```

Я работаю в Visual C++ 2010 Express.
Мне не понятно, - как аллокатор выделяет память внутри сигнатуры конструктора.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ :**
Здравствуйте уважаемый ixSci! Прошу прощение за слишком краткое описание проблемы. Мне казалось, что и так будет всё понятно.

ИТАК. Без строки `a->allocate(n)` возникает ошибка времени выполнения. При наличии данной строки Компилятор пишет следующее:

> error C2663: 'std::allocator<_Ty>::allocate' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Это сообщение происходит ТОЛЬКО при использовании данного конструктора. То есть, когда в исполняемом коде возникает объект, использующий этот конструктор. Например: `Vec<int> vc(5)`.

Теперь о моей компетенции. Я прочитал Г.Шилдт"Базовый курс С++" и заканчиваю изучать учебник С.Прата"Язык программирования С++ Лекции и упражнения". Опыт, конечно, небольшой. Но по меткому выражению Мэтью Уилсона, - "очень люблю заглядывать под капот." Кстати, в первом коде, который Вы мне прислали есть ошибка: Функция `construct()` имеет второй аргумент - ссылку на значение инициализирующего объекта. Без этого аргумента функция не работает. Есть и другие ошибки. Но в целом код даёт понимание, - как работает Аллокатор. Так что всё равно - СПАСИБО! Я добавил в Ваш код некоторые свои комментарии. Если хотите, я покажу то, что у меня получилось. И ЕЩЁ. Если можно, покажите, пожалуйста как должен выглядеть "НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ" вектор в котором память выделяется при помощи Аллокатора. Только "шапку", поля данных и ОДИН конструктор, создающий объект из "n" элементов и их инициализирующий. СПАСИБО!

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2** Уважаемые господа @ixSci и @Abyx ! Огромное СПАСИБО! Благодаря Вам я познакомился с Аллокаторами. Теперь я пришёл к ряду выводов. Хочется узнать, - верны ли они???

**ВЫВОДЫ:**

1. Аллокатор как параметр присутствует во всех конструкторах библиотечного контейнера `vector` только для инициализации его, - вектора, - базового класса, в котором и хранится Аллокатор. Мои конструкторы вектора не работали именно потому, что в них Аллокатор, уже объявленный в шаблоне класса, - повторно объявлялся и инициализировался.
2. Если удалить из памяти объекты при помощи метода`deallocate()`, предварительно не разрушив их при помощи метода`destroy()`, то эти объекты могут так и остаться в куче, что вызовет утечку памяти.
3. Закрытые поля данных `m_Start,m_Finish,m_Storage` следует помещать в конце объявления класса. Очевидно для того, чтобы Аллокатор быстрее построил Вектор и отключился.

**У меня остались вопросы.**

1. Зачем оставлять объекты в куче, в то время, как доступа к этим объектам уже не существует? То есть, почему бы не объединить `destroy()` и `deallocate()` в один метод?
2. Зачем в действительности поля `m_Start,m_Finish,m_Storahe` помещаются в конец объявления Вектора? Притом, что если эти поля поместить в начало Объявления Вектора, всё и так будет работать?

Comment: Уважаемый Abyx ! Прочитал предлагаемый Вами стандарт. Таких МАКРОСОВ так нет.

Comment: "Тут что-то не так" - это просто великолепное объяснение. Хотите, чтобы Вам помогли формулируйте вопрос нормально.

Comment: Уважаемый Abyx! У меня на компе стоит Visual Studio 2010 Express. И ОС "XP" для которой, - по идее,- прекращены обновления. Сам комп - Пень-3. Так что мне делать?

Comment: @NZMEY: (1) Обзавестить современным компьютером и поставить современный компилятор (это прекрасное вложение в собственное будущее). (2) Поставить cygwin или mingw, а на них свежий gcc. (3) Поставить современную, но не требовательную к ресурсам операционку (может быть, какой-нибудь дистрибутив линукса подойдёт, но я не уверен.)

Comment: @NZMEY: Возможно, вместо обновления стоит задать отдельный вопрос? Так много вопросов в одном не даёт возможности написать ответ по теме.

Comment: Ответил на последнее обновление.

Comment: Вопросы здесь никто не закрывает, если Вас удовлетворяет полученный ответ - пометьте его как лучший(галочка около ответа)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(T)` и `__STL_NOTHROW` это какие-то макросы, которые та или иная реализация библиотеки C++ использует. Они совершенно не нужны, для использования аллокатора.

Вот Вам пример использования стандартного, библиотечного аллокатора с комментариями:

```
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
};

int main()
{
    std::allocator<A> allocator; 
    size_t howMuch = 50;
    // Выделяем память под 50 структур A. Возвращённый указатель, указывает на неинициализированную память.
    A* allocatedArray = allocator.allocate(howMuch);
    A* allocatedItem = allocator.allocate(1);
    // Т.к. память не инициализирована, нам нужно её инициализировать. Для этого вызываем конструктор A явно
    allocator.construct(allocatedItem);
    // Для инициализации памяти под массив есть вспомогательная функция, которая сделает то же самое, что 
    // делает allocator по умолчанию
    std::uninitialized_fill_n(allocatedArray, howMuch, A());
    // После того, как наигрались с объектом, его нужно удалить, но сначала нужно вызвать деструктор
    allocator.destroy(allocatedItem);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < howMuch; ++i)
        allocator.destroy(allocatedArray + i);
    // Теперь освобождаем выделенную память
    allocator.deallocate(allocatedItem, 1);
    allocator.deallocate(allocatedArray, howMuch);
    return 0;
}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**
Во-первых, не храните указатель на аллокатор в объекте, храните сам объект аллокатора. Более того, мне не ясно, зачем Вы его копируете в конструкторе. Просто создавайте объект аллокатора согласно параметру шаблона и всё.
Во-вторых, у Вас есть очевидные ошибки в 2-х конструкторах:

```
Vec(int n, T t, const A & aaa = A())
    :a(&aaa)
{
    uninitialized_fill_n(bbb, n, t);
    eee = bbb + n;
    mmm = bbb + n;
    // Не работает.
}
```

Конечно не работает, кто будет память под `bbb` выделять? Добавьте: `bbb = a->allocate(n);`

```
Vec(const Vec< T, A> & vc)
{
    mmm = uninitialized_copy(vc.bbb, vc.mmm, bbb);
    eee = uninitialized_copy(vc.bbb, vc.eee, eee);
    // Не проверял.
}
```

Тот же комментарий про память, а потом нужно одно копирование:

```
Vec(const Vec< T, A> & vc)
{
    bbb = a->allocate(vc.mmm - vc.eee);
    mmm = uninitialized_copy(vc.eee, vc.mmm, bbb);
    eee = bbb;
}
```

Ну а по поводу:

> // Тут что-то не так. // Без этой строки - ошибка вермени выполнения.

Я не понимаю, что Вы этим хотели сказать. Что не так? Без какой строчки?

В целом, у меня создалось впечатление, что в C++ Вы очень сильно плавает, а лезть в аллокаторы, плавая в C++, это гиблое дело.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 2:**
Первое, код приведённый мной абсолютно корректен. Используйте последние доступные компиляторы, а не MSVS2010, который устарел. Это же касается нижеприведённого кода - используйте MSVS2013 для его компиляции.

Вот Вам минимальный пример, который содержит конструктор и деструктор для своего вектора:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class Vector
{;
public:
    Vector()
    {
        //Выделим немного памяти, чтобы не делать это при первом же push_back
        m_Storage = m_Allocator.allocate(m_Capacity);
    }

    Vector(size_t size):
        m_Size{size},
        m_Capacity{size*3/2}
    {
        //Выделим памяти немного больше, чем просили.
        m_Storage = m_Allocator.allocate(m_Capacity);
        //Инициализируем память, т.к. конструктор подразумевает созданные объекты
        std::uninitialized_fill_n(m_Storage, m_Size, T{});
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        for(auto it = m_Storage; it != m_Storage + m_Size; ++it)
            m_Allocator.destroy(it);
        m_Size = 0;
        m_Allocator.deallocate(m_Storage, m_Capacity);
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_Size;
    }
private:
    T* m_Storage;
    Alloc m_Allocator;
    size_t m_Size = 0;
    size_t m_Capacity = 10;
};
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ 3**

Касательно Ваших выводов:
Вывод **№2** неверный, `deallocate` освободит ранее выделенную память, но без `destroy` не будут вызваны деструкторы объектов, который были помещены в вектор. Вызовет ли это утечку? Это зависит от объектов, которые хранит вектор. Если это `Vector<int>`, то никаких проблем не будет. Если это `Vector<string>`, то память, которую `string` выделяет внутри себя никогда не будет освобождена. `destroy` обязательно должен быть вызван.

Вывод **№3** безосновательный. Члены класса можно помещать хоть в начало, хоть в конец. Это дело вкуса и ни на что не влияет. Просто я помещаю их в конец, я так привык.

По поводу вопроса **№1**: 
Потому что у аллокатора может быть такое внутреннее устройство, что он никогда не освобождает память, а лишь конструирует/разрушает объекты. Кроме того, операции выделения памяти и конструирования это две совершенно разные операции, которые должны иметь свои контр-пары. Их объединение не имеет смысла.

P.S. @NZMEY, пора прекратить эксплуатировать этот вопрос. Мы уже превращаем его в форум, а движок SO для этого не предназначен. Если будут ещё вопросы - создавайте ещё темы.

Comment: Уважаемый ixSci ! У меня не получается выделить память в конструкторе вектора. Функция "allocate()" не помогает. Вот что у меня получается :'template<class T,class A = allocator<T>>
class Vec{
 
 T* bbb ;
 T* eee ;
 T* mmm ;
 const A* a ;

public :

 Vec(const A & aaa = A())
  :bbb(nullptr),eee(nullptr),mmm(nullptr)
  ,a(&aaa)
  // Здесь всё нормально.
 {}


 Vec( size_t n  ,  const A & aaa = A() )
  :a(&aaa)
 {
  bbb = a->allocate( n ) ;
  // Так не получается.

  uninitialized_fill_n(bbb,n,T()) ;

  eee = bbb ;
  mmm = bbb + n ;
  
 }
'

Comment: @NZMEY, пожалуйста, не надо публиковать код в комментариях - ничего не понятно. Редактируйте свой вопрос и добавляйте новую информацию туда, после чего пишите комментарий, что Вы обновили вопрос. Теперь мой вопрос к Вам: что значит не получается?

Comment: А можно чуть-чуть подробнее. Как должен выглядеть ВЕСЬ код, выделяющий память при помощи функции "allocate()"?

Comment: @Abyx, с чего бы вдруг?

Comment: @NZMEY, `A* allocatedArray = allocator.allocate(howMuch);` - это ВЕСЬ код, выделяющий память.

Comment: Уважаемые господа! В конструкторе вектора который я написал такой код не работает. Кто-нибудь может ответить ПОЧЕМУ??? СПАСИБО!

Comment: @NZMEY, что значит "не работает"? Пока Вы не научитесь нормально задавать вопрос, Вы ответа не получите.

Comment: Уважаемый ixSci! Пожалуйста, прочитайте ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ моего вопроса. Я там подробно всё изложил. Спасибо!

Comment: @Abyx, `[container.requirements]` - это требования к стандартным контейнерам библиотеки C++, мы, как Вы можете видеть, пишем свой контейнер, а не контейнер для библиотеки. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, в стандарте приведёно использование функций аллокатора посредством вызова их через `allocator_traits` лишь по тому, что `allocator_traits` посвящён отдельный параграф, который позволяет наложить определённые ограничения на пользовательский аллокатор. И чтобы не повторять по 10 раз одно и то же в требованиях просто используется синтаксис `allocator_traits`

Comment: @Abyx, на мой взгляд этот параграф следует трактовать именно так. т.к. разницы между `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct ` и `allocator_type.construct ` ровно ноль целых, ноль десятых, что можно видеть в `[allocator.traits.members]`. Что, кстати, и делается в реализации стандартной библиотеки от MS - они просто вызывают `allocate`. Ну а если Вы всё же решите придраться и настаивать на своём, то, пожалуйста, найдите `[container.requirements]` использование функции `allocate`

Comment: @NZMEY, обновил ответ. Надеюсь на этот раз Вам будет достаточно кода, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: @Abyx, почитал я ещё про `allocator_traits` и понял, что моё "во-вторых" - не соответствует действительности. `allocator_traits` это действительно предпочтительный метод использования аллокаторов с точки зрения стандарта. Тем не мене, т.к. я не вижу преимуществ подобного подхода я код менять не стану.

Comment: @Abyx, спасибо! Поправил.